# How to display total price including shipping_lines, tax and product price of an order in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

How to display total price including shipping lines, tax and product price of an order in Shopify.

I have tried below JSON from postman to pass shipping amount and taxes.

```
{
  "order": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "title": "xyz",
        "variant_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "price": 22.7,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "price": "4.00",
        "title": "shipping",
        "carrier_identifier": "abc",
        "tax_lines": [
          {
            "price": 0.4,
            "rate": 0.1,
            "title": "GST"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "customer": {
      "email": "abc@yopmail.com"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "peter",
      "last_name": "T",
      "address1": "address1",
      "address2": "address2",
      "phone": "5555555555",
      "city": "Chapel en le frith HIGH PEAK",
      "country": "GB",
      "zip": "SK23 9UG"
    },
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "Peter",
      "last_name": "T",
      "address1": "address11",
      "address2": "address22",
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "city": "Chapel en le frith HIGH PEAK",
      "country": "GB",
      "zip": "SK23 9UG"
    },
    "note": "note",
    "financial_status": "paid"
  }
}
```

I'm getting total is sum of product price and shipping amount.
For example:
product price- $15.30
Shipping - $9.00
Tax - $0.90
Total - $24.3

But I want total to be sum of product price, Shipping amount and tax.
For example:
product price- $15.30
Shipping - $9.00
Tax - $0.90
Total - $25.20